# Resharper Inspection/Context Actions not working to only one file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, resharper, visual-studio-2017

I've been using Resharper for years but today I found Resharper inspection including *Context Action* (Ctrl+Enter bulbs) is not working to only single file (`MainViewModel.cs` in .NET4.6.2 WPF project) in solution.

This *No-inspection* symptom can be acknowledged by no yellow/green checkmark on top of editor scrollbar.

Here's what I've checked.

- I found encoding was not same as others so to change to `UTF8 BOM` as like others, but still not working.
- Close VS, Reinstall Resharper `2016.3.2`, all of them are not helped.
- There's no ignorance filter for this file in Resharper option.
- There's no solution-wide Resharper options.
- There's no code inspection pattern in Resharper options.
- This occurred in both `VS2015/VS2017` identically.
- such an inspection is working for all other cs files in same folder.

What can I do to check more for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by creating `MainViewModel.partial.cs` partial class and move codes to it. 
It works fine.

This is not a *solution*, so any reply could be welcomed.

Comment: Seems it was a Resharper bug. It is now fixed as of 2017.1.1

Comment: still seems present in 2017.3.1

Answer (score 5):

MainViewModel and ViewModelLocator are both omitted from ReSharper analysis.(Perhaps because they were added automatically as part of the MVVM Light NuGet package?) The fix is to right-click the "Pause" icon at the top of the vertical scrollbar and "Enable analysis" for the file. Click again and "Resume"

Comment: This is hidden! But thanks for that - I was originally using https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546989-ReSharper-stopped-working-for-a-single-specific-solution?page=2#comments this details on how to clear cache!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the ReSharper status icon in the upper right corner of the open tab. Maybe the analysis is disabled. You can resume analysis by right-clicking on this icon.
[image: ReSharper status icon]